# Implement setInterval using setTimeout

Tags: javascript

What would be a good approach to best implement `setInterval` using `setTimeout`?

Take into account that the mocked *setInterval* should be able to be "cleared".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What refrains you form using the built-in implementation?

Comment: because I was challenged by someone, for fun. not all programs have real-life purpose, and it's alright to create things for pure fun.

Comment: In that case would you accept this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50501356/how-to-create-your-own-settimeout-function/50503744#50503744) as a dupe? There the challenge was even more fun. Or even [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50115731/the-differences-of-setinterval-between-chrome-and-other-browsers-why/50115944#50115944) which shows an implementation with a real use case.

Comment: Of "implementing your own timing function with no real goal".

Comment: The post you linked to is not directly related to this one, and cannot be reached by a simple google query. this one is very simple and SEO friendly.

Comment: There is a real goal and I'm not obliged to tell it to you.

Comment: @JonasW. - it's **not** homework, look at my score, this is certainly not homework or task, but a question someone asked me to help him with, and I googled and saw there weren't any decent  results so decided to contribute to the internet with my own Q/A. I have been moderating myself this website for years now, and I find this information very interesting for the sake of other developers.

Comment: Hmm. I definetly answered this question more than once, so while i admit that this is not homework this definetly has a duplicate, but as I'm currently unable to find it (SO's search engine is not the best) I retract my vote and let others decide on this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Below code creates a mock implementation of `setInterval` using `setTimeout`

```js
function interval(cb, ms){
  var a = {
    clear : function(){
      clearTimeout(a.timer)
    }
  };
  (function run(){
    cb();
    a.timer = setTimeout(run, ms);
  })();
  
  return a;
}


var myInterval_1 = interval(()=>{ console.log(1) }, 1000); // create an "interval" 
var myInterval_2 = interval(()=>{ console.log(2) }, 1000); // create another "interval" 

// clear the first interval
setTimeout(()=>{ myInterval_1.clear() }, 4000)
```

Comment: That doesn't respect the specs at all.

Comment: @Kaiido - what specs? what are you talking about? this works, why the downvote?

Comment: Because setInterval implementation is specified by some documents, and that you don't apply these specifications, i.e adding a fool-guard against infinity loops.

Comment: you are taking all this too seriously. I am only having fun with javascript, a language which I love and code for the last 13 years.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see the fun in this implementation at all.

Comment: I don't need to ask your permission to ask thought-provoking fun questions regarding the fundamentals of the language. If you cannot see the fun in this, then please skip to another question sir.

Comment: agreed to you @vsynch

Comment: @vsync This is the simple and best implementation, I didn't understand why is there a downvote. In an interview also, this answer just doing the work. :)

Answer (score 4):

To mock *setInterval* accurately, ons has to mock *clearInterval* too:

```
{
  const intervals = new Map();

  function setInterval(fn, time, context, ...args) {
    const id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
    intervals.set(id, setTimeout(function next() {
       intervals.set(id, setTimeout(next, time));
       fn.apply(context, args);
    }, time));
    return id;
  }

  function clearInterval(id) { 
    clearTimeout(intervals.get(id));
  }
}
```

And you can use it as always:

```
 const interval = setInterval(console.log, 100, console, "hi");

clearInterval(interval);
```

Comment: I might be misreading (on a phone rn) but I think your implementation will make it impossible to clear the interval from the callback.

Answer (score 4):

Here the **intervalId** is the reference object that contains the **timeoutId**.
The reference object changes every time the setTimeout is called recursively.

```
const _setInterval = (callback, delay) => {
  const timerRef = { id: null };
  const timeout = () => {
    timerRef.id = setTimeout(() => {
      callback();
      timeout();
    }, delay);
  }
  timeout();
  return timerRef;
};

const timerRef = _setInterval(() => {
  console.log("Callback");
}, 1000);

setTimeout(() => {
  clearTimeout(timerRef.id);
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a promise based solution without recursion :)

```
function setInterval1(fn, time) {
    let check = { check: true };
    (async function () {
        for (let i = 0; i < Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY && check.check; i++) {
            await new Promise((resolve) => {
                setTimeout(() => { fn(); resolve(true); }, time);
            });
        }
    })();
    return check;
}

let check = setInterval1(() => console.log('hi'), 1000);

function clearInterval1(check) {
    check.check = false;
}

setTimeout(() => { clearInterval1(check) }, 4000)
```